# R ExpressionSet filter NA values

Tags: r, bioconductor

I want to create the following ExpressionSet in R:

```
dataDirectory <- system.file("extdata", package = "Biobase")
exprsFile <- "path to expression data.txt"
exprs <- as.matrix(read.table(exprsFile, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = 1, as.is = TRUE))

pDataFile <- "path to phenotype data.txt"
pData <- read.table(pDataFile, row.names=1, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
phenoData <- new("AnnotatedDataFrame",data=pData)
```

Now delete those columns from the exprs with more than 80% of NA values

```
exprs <- exprs[,colSums(is.na(exprs)) < 0.8]
```

Before I can execute the following code & build the ExpressionSet I have to delete all the rows in the phenoData (=samples) that match the above deleted columns in the exprs. How can I achieve that?

```
exampleSet <- ExpressionSet(assayData=exprs, phenoData=phenoData)
exampleSet
```

Answer (score 1):

Build the ExpressionSet (without filtering)

```
exampleSet <- ExpressionSet(assayData=exprs, phenoData=phenoData)
```

and then subset, using the `exprs()` function to work with the underling matrix of expression values:

```
exampleSet[, colSums(is.na(exprs(exampleSet))) < 0.8]
```

Ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Comment: Thank you for your solution!